# Sql - can I search for particular numbers in a record?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, records, sql-like

I have a column in a table that contains data like:

```
column: col_name
 row 1: 3451,3547,234,456,6487,2341,7856,546,76
 row 2: 4746,234,6757,234,7657,6346,563
 row 3: 546,7467,4562,456,234
 row 4: 563,3246,5641,4637,234,7854,567,577
```

I would like to be able to select a record based on whether it has a certain number in it.

E.g. as 234 appears in all rows, it selects them all; 563 appears in 2 and so on.
This does not work:

```
select col_name from table_name where col_name like '%234%';
```

which I think may be because I'm confusing how I should be selecting columns and rows, but I'm at a blank for what else could work, help appreciated!

Edit: I think I'm confusing myself and some of the repliers (sorry, folks). I'm not trying to find the column name that matches my query, I'm trying to find data in the column that matches my query, aka data in the rows. Some of the answers seem geared towards an unknown column name, but I know which column I'm using.

This is what I would expect to get if I search for a row with 563 in it:

```
4746,234,6757,234,7657,6346,563      (row 2)
563,3246,5641,4637,234,7854,567,577  (row 4)
```

If I search for it using all the values in the query like so:

```
select col_name from table_name where col_name = '4746,234,6757,234,7657,6346,563';
```

then it will return the row:

```
4746,234,6757,234,7657,6346,563      (row 2)
```

but I only want to be able to search for it using one number, not several, as they represent different things.

Comment: you mean,you want to match with whole number separated comma?

Comment: why select col_name from table_name where col_name like '%234%';
does not work?

Comment: good point - i want to match the number separated by the commas with whatever i'm searching for, so it finds ,234, and not ,1234, or similar. currently it returns an empty set :(

Comment: Search for "(^|,)234(,$)" with the "rlike" operator for exact number matches.

Comment: @bladepanthera you are doing some thing wrong,I ran this query successfully on my pc

Comment: You may get answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209955/regular-expression-in-mysql-query/12209979#12209979

Comment: does it make it clearer if I say that all the numbers are in one column? so row1 shows the contents of that one column

Comment: Can you post expected output for the input data which you have provided?

Comment: @Omesh I posted the output expected above

Comment: Updated my answer. See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da7e3/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT col_name 
FROM table_name 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('563', col_name);
```

## Example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da7e3/1)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the way you have stored your data in the database,accordingly select the pattern which includes comma n spaces as well.

your query is otherwise correct !!

Comment: @kat-06 I think that my query is correct for looking for a column with that number in the name of the column, but I'm trying to find a row in that column (I know the column) wit that number in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
      col_name
from table_name 
WHERE col_name LIKE '234,%'
OR col_name LIKE '%,234'
OR col_name LIKE '%,234,%'
OR col_name = '234'
```

Dont worry about rows. It will search through the rows you only have to provide the column name.

Comment: this is what i have been trying to use and it does not work. maybe it is due to no spaces?

Comment: means that it returns an empty set, when you can clearly see that a record contains that number in the column

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT col_name
FROM   table_name 
WHERE  concat(',',col_name,',') like '%,234,%';
```

Comment: also no luck. i don't understand why you would put the column name between ','s as i'm looking for a number, not the column name

Comment: @bladepanthera: I am adding a comma at both ends of the col_name to match with the number appears at the beginning and end of the col_name.. I doubt there is some problem in the data, other wise this query should work.. plz check

Comment: ok, ive definitely phrased my question incorrectly i think: I want to find the data in the column, not the column itself! So 234 is a number in one of the rows in the column.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

> SELECT col_name FROM   table_name  WHERE  ','+col_name+',' like
>   '%,234,%';

Comment: returns empty set. also, I have a known column so I don't see why I would need the '+', thanks anyway

Comment: i have tried it and it is working for me,it will surely work for you